# Wordpress - User comments shows the time of post - NOT the time of comment

Tags: wordpress

See the problem here:
http://www.codywilliamsmma.com/cody-williams-vs-martin-guerra/

If you look at the date of the post "09/09/2009", then look at the time I commented on the post "2 years, 328 days ago" ... It's equaling out to the exact time of the post date! Which is very wrong. It should say something like "3 hours ago" since I posted it earlier today.

This is a plugin for wordpress called WP-Days-Ago, the plugin has lots of great reviews and I don't think the problem is on they're end. I think it's something I might have tampered with in one of the comments php files (since I custom built this theme).. All that being said, I'm still uncertain.

Does anyone have any idea on what it might be?

Comment: Check the codes on your `comments.php` file.

Comment: What am I exactly looking for though? What would be the cause of this problem?

Comment: First de-activate that "WP-Days-Ago" plugin and then check how the comment's date showing. Then we will be able to know is it a plugin problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for 'date' while in the editor and looking at the comments.php file.

See what that looks like does it say post date or similar?

It should look something along the lines of:

```
 <?php comment_date('F jS, Y') ?>
```

Comment: I didn't put the `<?php wp_days_ago(); ?>` into the themes "comments.php" file, I put it in "wordpress/wp-includes/comment-template.php" file. See it here: [ http://oneillwebs.com/mma/comment-template.txt ] if you do a ctrl+f for `wp_days_ago`, you will see where the code lives.. if you look directly above that you will find: `get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time()`, I'm installing a fresh version of wordpress locally and see where I might've went wrong but any guidance will still help!